# React json set array object without existing value

Tags: reactjs, arrays, json, object, react-hooks

I have an array object (venue.products) that may or may not be prefilled depending whether it has been saved before. If its pre-filled (venue.products), the code works and I can update it but if not, it errors, as the venue.products does not exist. What is the best way to set a value to it, if it does not exist prior?

```
const handleDayPriceChange = (e) => {
  venue.products ? setVenue({ ...venue,
    products: [{ ...venue.products[0],
      price: e.target.value,
    }, ...venue.products.slice(1)]
  }) : console.log("how to set initially when venue.products has no value?")
};
```

With the previous, I am trying to update the price of the first object in a case where it does not exist before. The json for venue if it exists:

```
{
  "products": [{
      "name": "meetingRoom1",
      "price": "695"
    },
    {
      "name": "meetingRoom2",
      "price": "125"
    },
  ]
  "id": "3123",
  "users": "555"
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const handleDayPriceChange = (e) => {
  setVenue(prev => { 
    const products = prev?.products?.slice() || [{}];
    products[0]?.price = e.target.value,
    return {
      ...prev,
      products
    }
  }) : console.log("how to set initially when venue.products has no value?")
};
```

Comment: Hi @Steve, sorry there is a misunderstanding.

Its only the second ternary operator (console.log) part that I need the helpfor. The first part works fine.
The question is, how do I set the value to venue.products[0].price in the case that the value does not exist (in the initial venue json its just products: "''",)?